Launchpad error while copying package -- already published
I'm trying to copy my Launchpad package to the new Noble repo,

I first tried to copy binary package but failed with:

Target series: Noble
my-pkg 1.1.0-1 in jammy (binaries conflicting with the existing ones)


I then tried to copy source package but still failed:

Target series: Noble
my-pkg 1.1.0-1 in focal (same version already has published binaries in the destination archive)

This is wrong, as the first copy failed, and I don't see it when I tried to "Delete package" myself.
I think this is more or less a launchpad internal error, but
is there anything I can do about it please?

You cannot use 1.1.0-1 again.
Because you already uploaded it to the PPA for any release, you have already used that version string.  You cannot reuse the same string for another version.
You need individual PPA uploads with independent versions for each Ubuntu release.
I.E. you need to make a few uploads with different target distros and releases:

1.1.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 for Focal
1.1.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1 for Jammy
1.1.0-1~ubuntu24.04.1 for Noble

Even though you deleted the package the PPA remembers all uploaded versions.  Copying the same source for rebuilding in different Ubuntu releases isn't possible and you need independent version strings and PPA uploads for those releases to the PPA.

Ah, that's why. thx. What's interesting is that, copying the binary package allows me to reuse 1.1.0-1 again and again. Just to make a full story as where the illusion is coming from.

@xpt Copying of the binaries only copies built .deb files from one release to another.  Which is bad because .deb built on older libraries, etc. might not work on newer releases and vice versa.  Binary copying is only a solution if you KNOW it won't break on older/newer releases. The only surefire way here is multiple uploads of the base version to your PPA for building with native libs on each release. Note I also updated my answer with different version strings because if this lands in the repository you probably want it to override the PPAs if newer is in the main repos compared to PPA
